# Bootstrap Carousel w/captions in separate div w/o show/hide animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've put together this slider w/bootstrap and some javascript taken/adjusted from other places and it's all looking fine except I want to get rid of the little transition/animation that happens when the caption changes.

It looks like the captions sort of slide in/out but I just want them to immediately appear/disappear. I'm afraid it might be something in the bootstrap javascript but I'm not sure how to fix it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" id="carousel-1">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item"><img class="w-100 d-block" src="https://cdn.bootstrapstudio.io/placeholders/1400x800.png" alt="Slide Image" /></div>
        <div class="carousel-item"><img class="w-100 d-block" src="https://cdn.bootstrapstudio.io/placeholders/1400x800.png" alt="Slide Image" /></div>
        <div class="carousel-item active"><img class="w-100 d-block" src="https://cdn.bootstrapstudio.io/placeholders/1400x800.png" alt="Slide Image" /></div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev"><span aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a href="#carousel-1" role="button" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next"><span aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="slider-captions">
    <div>
        <div id="caption-0" class="pp-carousel-caption">
            <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="caption-1" class="pp-carousel-caption">
            <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="caption-2" class="pp-carousel-caption">
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("#carousel-1").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(evt) {

   var step = $(evt.relatedTarget).index();

   $('#slider-captions .pp-carousel-caption:not(#caption-'+step+')').hide( function() {
        $('#caption-'+step).show();
   });

});
```

CSS:

```
.pp-carousel-caption:not(#caption-0) {
    display: none;
}

.pp-carousel-caption:not(#caption-0) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the duration to `0` with the first parameter, the default value is `400`.

```
$('#slider-captions .pp-carousel-caption:not(#caption-'+step+')').hide(0, function() {
     $('#caption-'+step).show(0);
});
```

- https://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete
- https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete